# How can work on eclipse for Bazel project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bazel, bazel-extra-action

Is there way using eclise for bazel project,  there is guide https://github.com/bazelbuild/eclipse . Eclipse plugin for Bazel,  but I can not find Eclipse 4 Bazel on installation

Comment: There is an Eclipse plugin for Bazil (e4b) at the link you cited.  It isn't a "guide" - it's a plugin..You can read what it does [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/eclipse/blob/master/README.md).  It doesn't look like the install instructions work.  But you can try checking out the project and building it yourself, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's only the e4b plugin (as [@paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421195/paulsm4) says), which unfortunately seems to be unmaintained.

I don't know of any other Eclipse plugin for Bazel.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2019, there is now a new option, the Bazel Eclipse Feature:

https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-eclipse

Currently it only supports Java development for Bazel workspaces, but over time we hope to make it more comprehensive.

Comment: Tried this. But the documentation and the actual behavior doesn't match. https://github.com/salesforce/bazel-eclipse/blob/master/docs/using_the_feature_import.md says to browse to the location of workspace file. But instead of location we have to select the workspace file.
After importing , it gives error  - Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-11]' in project 'Bazel Workspace (root)'. 
Even though I have already added  build --javacopt=-source 8 -target 8 in the .bazelrc file
Also no projects shown in the project view .

Answer (score 0):

Since bazel is easy to read, I prefer the vim editor to edit these files for my C++ project. I also have my 'old' style Eclipse projects, so can build in two ways: Using Eclipse or using Bazel. It is very convenient for me to convert projects slowly to Bazel, whenever I have some time.